# Using float in my CSS breaks the layout

Tags: html, css

Here's a before and after picture. When I add a float:left to the li, the layout breaks and the div that's supposed to be below this topmenu div, floats up.

[image]
[image]

Here's the CSS:

```
#topmenu
{
    background-color:#335D7C;    
}

#topmenu ul
{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#topmenu ul li
{    
    background-image: url('../Content/Images/topmenutick.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color:White;
    float:left;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
}

#topmenu ul li a
{    
    text-decoration:none;
}

#topmenu ul li a:hover
{    
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `clear: both;` to whatever element is supposed to be below the floated list.

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML as well? It **looks** like you're missing a clear: left; after the #topmenu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the elements don't take a full-width bounding box anymore. They all float to the left, and the following content runs right up to the end of the floating box. Add `clear:left;` to the CSS of the following element.

Alternatively, you can use a generated element to clear the float. Google for `clearfix`.

Comment: This was the solution. I added 'clear:both' to the div in orange and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should control the urge of using floats.

```
#topmenu ul li
{    
    ...
}
```

<strike>float:left;</strike>
        **display: inline;**

Answer (score 0):

Use a cleaner div after the floated element.
CSS:

```
.cl {
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cl"></div>
```

Comment: Why add elements just to give them a css rule that can be applied to any pre-existing element?

Comment: @David Thomas: Maybe just my bad habit.

Comment: fair enough, I guess. But that way lies the madness of [tag-soup](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tag_soup), and [divitis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divitis)...

Comment: @David Is it good to add just the cleaner class to the next element even if it has a class already, for example `<div class="next_divs_class cl">` or is it better to avoid the `.cl` class entirely and add the `clear: both` to the CSS for every class which needs it?